# HikariPool-1 - Interrupted during connection acquisition

Tags: java, sql, mariadb, hikaricp, bungeecord

So I'm trying to get a connection and it doesn't work and gives me this nice exception (which I don't semm to understand):

```
11:17:07 [SEVERE] java.sql.SQLException: HikariPool-1 - Interrupted during connection acquisition
> 11:17:07 [SEVERE] at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:200)
> 11:17:07 [SEVERE] at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:161)
> 11:17:07 [SEVERE] at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:100)
> 11:17:07 [SEVERE] at net.bungeencoin.mcn.sql.DatabaseConnecter.getConnection(DatabaseConnecter.java:48)
> 11:17:07 [SEVERE] at net.bungeencoin.mcn.sql.Database.getCoins(Database.java:31)
> 11:17:07 [SEVERE] at net.bungeencoin.mcn.listeners.CacheListener.lambda$onJoin$0(CacheListener.java:27)
> 11:17:07 [SEVERE] at net.md_5.bungee.scheduler.BungeeTask.run(BungeeTask.java:63)
> 11:17:07 [SEVERE] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> 11:17:07 [SEVERE] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> 11:17:07 [SEVERE] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> 11:17:07 [SEVERE] Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
> 11:17:07 [SEVERE] at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:944)
> 11:17:07 [SEVERE] at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.ConcurrentBag.borrow(ConcurrentBag.java:157)
> 11:17:07 [SEVERE] at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:179)
> 11:17:07 [SEVERE] ... 9 more
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar issue. Were you able to find any solution?

Comment: Hi it’s been a long time but if I remember I had to close the connections myself to fix the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error means that you had one or more long-running SQL statements that were holding onto all the connections in your Hikari connection pool, and during that period something else called "Interrupt" on your application, calling all blocking threads to throw an interrupt exception at the point where they were blocking.

Hikari CP uses blocking constructs for thread safety, hence this stack trace occurred.

Relevant GitHub issue
https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/976

Here is a classic blog post on the subject if InterruptedException:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/index.html

Comment: The IBM link is broken.

Comment: Oops. That's a shame. It seems if you search the internet (google, etc) for "Handling InterruptedException" the article has been copy-pasted to other sites.